# Instant.now(new NanoClock()) returns incorrect time

Tags: java, system-clock

we are having a piece of code where we are using NanoClock to get the exact time. In a nut shell below is the code snippet of how i am generating the nano time and how we are converting to simple date format. the problem is, nono time (in some cases) is off by few seconds. so for eg, the system time is 12:23:**44**.125 the nano time will be 12:23:**56**.1234567.

```
public static Date getTimeStamp() {
    final Clock clock = new NanoClock();
    Instant instant = Instant.now(clock);
    return Timestamp.from(instant);
}

public static Date getTimeInMilis(Timestamp timestamp) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String miliDate = dateFormat.format(timestamp);
    return dateFormat.parse(miliDate);
}
```

we are using **NanoClock** as follows

```
public static final long NANOS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000;

private static final long EPOCH_NANOS = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000;
private static final long NANO_START = System.nanoTime();

final long now = System.nanoTime() - NANO_START + EPOCH_NANOS;
return Instant.ofEpochSecond(now / NANOS_PER_SECOND, now % NANOS_PER_SECOND);
```

we were running this code in production for over 5 years and it was always fine. it started giving this discrepancy since past 2 months.
we are using JAVA 8 update 71 (64 bits) and nothing has changed on the system with respect to JAVA or my code in past 4-5 months.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/759730/how-much-clock-drift-is-considered-normal-for-a-non-networked-windows-7-pc).

Comment: Why are you using the outdated and buggy Date class?  Unless absolutely required,  you should be using classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: @Nathan : thanks for the pointer. but my issue works fine for some occurances and fails for other. if, for eg, i execute the sample code 3000 time in a day then it will work fine for about 600-1000 times and return expected result. for other times it give some random results. for some instances it is off by 1few milli seconds of others it is 2 sec or 3 sec or 4 sec and so on.. also, i am on windows server 2019

Comment: @g00se :  thanks for your answer. due to compliance requirement in Europe, i am trying to get times from two different places. 1) using new Date() to get time in milli seconds for one field 2) using the nanosecond time which i mentioned about to get the compliance. problem is, the difference between 1 and 2 is off by more than 2 seconds in some cases. i am ok if they are off by a second or two. thats ok. if cant be off by more than 2 seconds

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. It sounds like you should be doing something more like getting two `ZonedDateTime` instances and from these deriving two `Instant`s

Answer (score 3):

The discrepancy is due to system clock drift.

[`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) is vulnerable to adjustments in the system clock, for example from the NTP daemon.
On the other hand [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) is a value that increases by 10<sup>9</sup> every second, irrespective of any adjustments to the system clock.

Whenever there is such an adjustment, you will get a divergence between `NanoClock`, which calls `System.currentTimeMillis()` once and stores its result, and something which calls `System.currentTimeMillis()` each time, like `new Date()`.

---

`NanoClock` is buggy.

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns `X` while the current time is `X milliseconds + Y microseconds + Z nanoseconds`.

So `EPOCH_NANOS` is `Y microseconds + Z nanoseconds` before the correct epoch.

---

Note that `System.nanoTime()` provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes).

---

From Java 9 onwards, [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) gives you the current system time with nanosecond precision (but not nanosecond resolution).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you fully understand how milliseconds / nanoseconds work in the jvm.

You can only compare two `System.nanoTime()` values to see how many nanoseconds have elapsed. You can't use them to construct `Date` or `Instant` instances.

The following is not valid

```java
private static final long EPOCH_NANOS = System.currentTimeMillis()*1000000;
```

The result of this multiplication might exceed `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Please explain what you are trying to achieve as I feel this might be an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). For instance you might be able to create a `StopWatch` class based on `System.nanoTime()` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Well... as I said `System.nanoTime()` can only really be used as a sort of stop watch to count the nanos that have elapsed between events in the same JVM. `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` are not compatible and can't be compared with one another. As you possibly know `new Date()` and `ZonedDateTime.now()` etc are all based on `System.currentTimeMillis()` and cannot be compared with `System.nanoTime()`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a naive test, but how are you going to adjust for accuracy when subsequent calls take inconsistent times well below your expected precision requirements.  The values change per run.  The first can probably be ignored for startup time.

```
long[] times = new long[20];        
times[0] = System.nanoTime();       
times[1] = System.nanoTime();       
times[2] = System.nanoTime();       
times[3] = System.nanoTime();       
times[4] = System.nanoTime();       
times[5] = System.nanoTime();       
times[6] = System.nanoTime();       
times[7] = System.nanoTime();       
times[8] = System.nanoTime();       
times[9] = System.nanoTime();       
times[10] = System.nanoTime();      
times[11] = System.nanoTime();      
times[12] = System.nanoTime();      
times[13] = System.nanoTime();      
times[14] = System.nanoTime();      
times[15] = System.nanoTime();      
times[16] = System.nanoTime();      
times[17] = System.nanoTime();      
times[18] = System.nanoTime();      
times[19] = System.nanoTime();      
                                    
                                    
for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i+=2) {
    System.out.println(times[i+1] - times[i]);
}
```

prints

```
200
100
100
0
0
0
0
0
0
100
```